# Shortage of Pi cameras in the market?

Tags: camera, raspicam

I tried buying raspi cam v2 NoIR from raspberrypi.org listed websites in India. Most of the websites listed had no availability of the camera. One of the websites had it and its been 3 weeks since I ordered and I haven't received the camera yet. Is there a shortage of Pi Cameras in the market?

Comment: Have you tried AliExpress? - (1) https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/NewRaspberry-Pi-Camera-V2-Video-Module-8MP/32665543044.html (2) https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/raspberry-pi-camera.html

Comment: Shopping suggestions are off-topic. (I suppose arguable asking about a shortage might be different, but there's no archival value to a question about the current supply of cameras.)

Comment: @Brick Shopping suggestions are off topic is for sure the common way to think of the question as. But archival value is important to people who build stuff around hardware products. This data is for sure helpful for people in the future when they plan their project timelines.

Comment: I think that Brick's comment covers the key issue here. The current stock is of very little relevance to future readers as the information posted as an answer are short lived and are subject to a quick change.

Comment: @Ghanima I think the past stock of any product is of relevance to any hardware manufacturer like me, I deal with the shortage at this day when I have to be releasing my product. Any such posts would have helped me in having the situation under control. I would suggest the community to be open to use cases and not stick to age old rules and consider this as a shopping suggestion related query.

Comment: @55597 Thank you for your input. Feel free to call for a reopen of your question, I will not interfere. Any discussion about making this a policy should be taken to Meta however. Please feel free to post a question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK at the moment:

- [PiHut](https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-noir-camera-module) and [Pimironi](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/raspberry-pi-camera-module-v2-1-with-mount?variant=19833929799) both have stock.
- [RS components](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/video-modules/9132673/) have just shy of 13K ready to go.
- [Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/raspberry-pi/rpi-noir-camera-board/raspberry-pi-noir-camera-board/dp/2510729) are out until september.
- [Pi supply](https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/raspberry-pi-noir-infrared-camera-board-v2-1-8mp-1080p) are also out.

I was to see a couple out of stock which may suggest a delay somewhere?

I'm guessing postage costs to India would be significant?

Comment: Please note that shopping suggestions are off-topic and violate our policies. Please have a look at it at [How do I write a good answer?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). There you will find "*..avoid trying to answer questions which... are not about raspberry pi as [defined in the help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*".